# Show that $x^3y^3(x^3+y^3) \leq 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $x,y$ are positive reals such that $x+y = 2$ show that $x^3y^3(x^3+y^3) \leq 2$.

I thought about working backwards on this one. We can try to prove that $x^3y^3(x^3+y^3) \leq 2$ is true by first realizing that $x^3+y^3 = (x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$ and substituting in for $x+y = 2$. We then get $x^3y^3(x^2-xy+y^2) \leq 1$. How do I prove this is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $x^2-xy+y^2=(x+y)^2-3xy=4-3xy.$
So, now you have to prove that $$(xy)^3(4-3xy) \leq 1,$$
which can be done as follows:

> AM-GM inequality gives 
> $$\left(\frac{xy+xy+xy+(4-3xy)}{4}\right)^4 \geq (xy)^3(4-3xy)$$

Answer (score 0):

we have $$(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3+3xy(x+y)$$ since $$x+y=2$$ we get $$8-6xy=x^3+y^3$$ plugging this in the given inequality we obtain $$6(xy)^4-8(xy)^3+2\geq 0$$  but this is equivalent to $$(3(xy)^2+2xy+1)(xy-1)^2\geq 0$$ and this is true.

Answer (score 0):

One has $$x^3(2-x)^3[x^3+(2-x)^3]$$ Changing $x$ by $1+z$ it follows
$$(1+z)^6(1-z)^3+(1+z)^3(1-z)^6$$ Hence the curve is symmetric respect to the axe $z=0$ and it has its maximun at $z=0$. This maximun is $2$ and it is clearly the same of the initial function in $x$ because the function in $z$ is a translation of $x$.