# If $x+y=2$ then show that $x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)≤2$

Tags: proof-verification, inequality

> Let $x$ and $y$ be two positive real numbers such that $x+y=2$. Then show that $$x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)≤2,$$

---

In  [$x+y=2$ implies $x^3y^3(x^3+y^3)≤2$, for positive $x$ and $y$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2551700/xy-2-implies-x3y3x3y3%E2%89%A42-for-positive-x-and-y/2551735#2551735)  we can see that $t=xy$ solves pretty simple. But here we get 
$$t^2(4-2t) \leq \Big({t+t+4-2t\over 3}\Big)^3 = {64\over 27}$$
which is greater than $2$.

Edit: Ahh, true it is not that much harder than I thought at first. Since $$0\leq t =xy\leq \Big({x+y\over 2}\Big)^2 =1$$
we have $$(t-1)(t^2-t-1)\geq 0$$
which is equivalent to $$t ^2(4-2t)\leq 2$$

Comment: What do you mean by *but harder*?! Please add your attempts. By setting $y=(2-x)$ this is just a maximization problem for a single-variable function over $[0,2]$, pretty simple.

Comment: @ChristianF: over $(0,2)$, the derivative of $f(x)=x^2(2-x)^2(x^2+(2-x)^2)$ only vanishes at $x=1$, hence it is straightforward to prove that $f(x)\leq f(1)=2$ for any $x\in[0,2]$, done.

Comment: @ChristianF: it is given by $4 (-2+x) (-1+x) x \left(4-6 x+3 x^2\right)$. The roots at $0,1,2$ are obvious and it just remains to check that the discriminant of the quadratic factor is negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume that $$x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)>2$$ A $x+y=2$, we have $x^2+y^2=4-2xy$. Substituting this in the inequality above, we get $$4x^2y^2-2x^3y^3>2$$ This implies that $$2x^2y^2>1+x^3y^3$$ This is a contradiction because $2x^2y^2\leq 1+x^4y^4$ by AM-GM inequality, and $1+x^4y^4\leq 1+x^3y^3$. The last inequality is true because $xy\leq 1$, which is something we get by applying the AM-GM inequality to the equation $x+y=2$.

Hence proved

Answer (score 1):

it is equivalent to $$ (xy)^3-(xy)^2+\frac{1}{2}\geq 0$$ which is true. Consider the function $$h(t)=t^3-t^2+\frac{1}{2}$$ for $t>0$
$$h'(t)=3t^2-t$$ and $$h''(t)=6t>0$$ and $$h(1/3)>0$$

Answer (score 1):

Put $x=2\cos^2(t) $

and   $y=2\sin^2 (t) .$

then

$$x^2y^2=16\cos^4 (t)\sin^4 (t)=\sin^4 (2t)$$

and

$$x^2+y^2=4 \Bigl(1-2\sin^2 (t)\cos^2 (t)\Bigr)$$
$$=4-2\sin^2 (2t) $$
Let $f (z)=z^2 (2-z) $ for $0\le z\le 1$.

$$f'(z)=2z (2-z)-z^2=z (4-3z)$$

the maximum of $f (z) $ is attained for $z=1$ thus

$$x^2y^2 (x^2+y^2)=2f (\sin^2 (2t))\le 2f (1)\le 2$$

Comment: The very last inequality looks problematic.

Comment: yes, $-2 \leq -2\sin^2(2t)$, but then $4 - 2 \leq 4 - 2\sin^2(2t)$, which is the opposite of your statement

Comment: @Ronald It looks correct now.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=1+k$ and $y=1-k$, for some $k\in(-1,1)$. Then
\begin{align}
x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)&=(1-k^2)^2\times2(1+k^2)\\
&=2(1-k^2)(1-k^4)\\
&\le 2
\end{align}
Further, equality holds iff $k=0$, i.e. $x=y=1$.

Comment: Answered it to a duplicate of this question initially, copying here so that nobody misses this easy approach.