# prove the inequality $x + y = 2$. Prove that $x^2y^2 (x^2 + y^2)\leq2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Positive numbers  $x + y = 2$. Prove that $x^2y^2 (x^2 + y^2)\leq2$

Comment: hint: $x^2+y^2={(x+y)}^2-2xy=4-xy$ Now see the expression as a function in $xy$

Comment: How far have you gotten with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $x+y=2$ then show that $x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)≤2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2663851/if-xy-2-then-show-that-x2y2x2y2%e2%89%a42)

Comment: @Aqua just saw your  post, I am astonished to see a total score of -3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting $y=2-x$ and substituting this into the inequality we have $$ x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)-2\le 0 \Longleftrightarrow
(x^4 - 4x^3 + 5x^2 - 2x - 1)(x - 1)\le 0.
$$
Since $y=2-x\ge 0$ we have $0<x<2$. Now show that the claimed inequality is true for all such $x$.

Comment: Beat me to it. How are you so fast?

Comment: True, but it's also a race to get the first answer because the first answer sometimes gets accepted before I've even finished writing my (2nd answer). Anyway, it is what it is....

Answer (score 7):

Let $x=1+k$ and $y=1-k$, for some $k\in(-1,1)$. Then
\begin{align}
x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)&=(1-k^2)^2\times2(1+k^2)\\
&=2(1-k^2)(1-k^4)\\
&\le 2
\end{align}
Further, equality holds iff $k=0$, i.e. $x=y=1$.

Comment: Cool trick! I just loved it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

$x^2 y^2 (x^2+y^2) - 2 \leq 0\iff x^2y^2(4-2xy) - 2 \leq 0 \iff -2(xy-1)(x^2y^2 - xy -1) \leq 0$

---

**edit.**

This is actually what @Albus Dumbledore suggested in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

$$y = 2 - x \implies x^2y^2 (x^2 + y^2) = x^2(2-x)^2(x^2 + (2-x)^2)$$ $$= f(x) = 2x^6 - 12x^5 + 28x^4 - 32x^3 + 16x^2.$$

Now if we can find the maximum of $\ f(x)\ $ for $\ 0 < x < 2\ $ then we are done.

$$f'(x) = 12x^5 - 60x^4 + 112x^3 - 96x^2 + 32x.$$

By inspection, this can be factorised fully as:

$$\ f'(x) = 4x(x-1)(x-2)(3x^2-6x+4)$$

$ \implies x = 1\ $ is the only stationary point for $\ 0 < x < 2.\ $ Now note that $f(1) = 2.$

We must also check the end-points: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) = 0,\ $ and $\ \displaystyle\lim_{x\to 2^-}f(x) = 0.$

Hence, the maximum of $\ f(x)\ $ is $\ 2,\ $ and this occurs when $\ x = 1.$

Comment: You're factorizing 5 degree polynomial just for solving this!

Comment: No, wolframalpha did it for me lol.

Comment: Then you didn't solve it by inspection :P

Comment: I never said *I* solved it by inspection. I said, “By inspection, this can be factorised fully...”. But now you’re making me defend myself like a politician haha